# Почему компилятор пишет null

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog();
        dog1.setName("Бобик");
        dog1.voice();
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animals {

}

public class Animals {
    private String name;
    private String colors;
    private int size;

    public void setName(String UserName){
        UserName = name;
    }

    public void voice(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }


}
```

Comment: Потому, что String - это ссылочный тип данных и по умолчанию инициализируется "null". В аргументе метода println() метода voice() у тебя переменная "name" типа String. Вот и выводится на консоль "null".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void setName(String UserName)
{
    name = UserName; // !!! в другую сторону
}
```